# how does an android application (e.g web browser, facebook, whatsapp, gmail, video player url streaming e.tc) access a java.net.socket for internet?

Tags: java, android, html, .net, xml

I developed a custom Socket class from a separate package in the core java package library using eclipse IDE, it contains Socket and SocketImpl classes. I want networking apps to default to them for internet.

I do have some experience in coding and unpacking and packing android apps.

so, how do i do it?

after searching online, i tried opening up some android browsers, facebook, whatsapp, gmail, etc looking for  main activity java sources to see if i need to import my classes but it was so difficult, i couldnt tell which class was right for importing or even if i'm using the correct procedure. i thought this would be straightforward but its complicated.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you want. You can use Socket.connect(). And then the rest. What is the problem?

Comment: @blackapps, thank you sir for the reply. I know all about the Socket parameters and how to define them including connect.  What I really want to know is how to link or interface the Socket class file to the app and make the app use it like an attached module or sort - how do i combine them e.g Socket + web browser or Facebook etc?  What is the standard procedure?

Comment: Si you want a browser like Chrome let use your socket stuff?

Comment: @blackapps. yes sir